# How to insert an un-aligned equation inside an aligned equation block?

Tags: align

Here is a block of LaTeX that contains an un-aligned equation between 2 aligned equation blocks.

```
\begin{gather*}
    \begin{align*}
        a &= b (c + d)&\\
          &= bc + bd&
    \end{align*}\\
    [ \text{as } bc = zx \text{, and } bd = zy \text{, (this may be a long description occupying one line)} ]\\
    \begin{align*}
          &= zx + zy&\\
          &= z(x + y)&
    \end{align*}\\
\end{gather*}
```

The output looks like :

```
           a = b(c + d)
             = bc + bd
[as bc = zx, and bd = zy, (this may be a long description occupying one line)]
    = zx + zy
    = z(x + y)
```

You should notice that the "equal" sign in the second aligned block is not placed in the same position as the first aligned block.

I want to know that is there a way to align the "equal" sign in the second aligned block so that it is placed at the same position as the first aligned block. i.e. It should look like :

```
           a = b(c + d)
             = bc + bd
[as bc = zx, and bd = zy, (this may be a long description occupying one line)]
             = zx + zy
             = z(x + y)
```

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\intertext` to add a line of text between aligned blocks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
    \begin{align*}
        a &= b (c + d)&\\
          &= bc + bd&
     \intertext{as $bc = zx$, and  $bd = zy$, (this may be a long description occupying one line)}
          &= zx + zy&\\
          &= z(x + y)&
    \end{align*}\\
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: but the un-aligned part may be a long and complicated mathematical equation.

Comment: If it is a long complicated mathematical expression that does not fit on a lintel line, probably you should write in in a different way, not interwinding the two.

Comment: \intertext{} is a text mode environment. It seems a bit difficult to align content if we turn it into "displaystyle" math mode using $$. However, "textstyle" math equation content seems align OK. Perhaps it may be a solution for not too complicated inter equation.

Comment: If you have to interleave a displayed formula, how do you know that the block below is not a continuation of the interleaved formula? Also if is very long, the alignment can be in a different page as well. This is why I suggested to present the computation in a different way.

Comment: It seems that we could insert display style math by using \intertext{e.g. $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^m x^2 $}. Then this would solve my problem. Thanks.